# PowerShell - Check if Java Application is running, if not - restart it. (Javaw.exe doesn't show details)

Tags: java, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I've had a good search around, but can't quite find what I'm looking for.

We have Java applications running 24/7 on several remote machines which intermittently crashes (We think the application's devs are working on it) but for the time being, we need a way of restarting this application should it fail.

Now... the tricky thing is, as far as I can see at least, is that there's no way of telling if the application is running at all as only Javaw.exe shows in task manager. Even with the command line column, it only points to javaw.exe.

The reason we can't just check if Javaw is running, is because we have another Java application that isn't used as much (it's like a web based CRM software) This also starts Javaw.exe when needed, and also doesn't show up as a process.

It would be easy enough to just restart the Javaw.exe, if it didn't cause horrendous problems to the CRM side of things.

I'm not the best at PowerShell, but do have a grasp of it. I'm just out of ideas.

I hope you guys can help.

Thanks for your time.

ARc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200676/find-name-of-jar-in-javaw-exe-process-list) may help.
It basically uses `jps` that is included in JRE/JDK to get more fine grained info of javaw.

You can then parse the output and determine whether the app is still running.

Comment: Thanks for this, It's just what I'm looking for. Got a working script now! Basically just querying jps as to whether an app started with C:\JavaApp.jar and if it did, alls good. If not, launch it! Perfect! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

JMX may be the solution for your problem. In the case you can modify your Java apps.

[Java Management Extensions (JMX) is a Java technology that supplies tools for managing and monitoring applications, system objects, devices (e.g. printers) and service oriented networks. Those resources are represented by objects called MBeans (for Managed Bean). In the API, classes can be dynamically loaded and instantiated. Managing and monitoring applications can be designed and developed using the Java Dynamic Management Kit.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Management_Extensions)

Here's a tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately we aren't able to modify the Java apps as they are made by a third party. We're managing the IT systems remotely and unfortunately these issues are one of our main problems that we deal with.

Comment: (oops, return apparently sends the message) The software developers themselves say this can be achieved with PowerShell, but I'm not entirely convinced.